# Monterey Zathura Install

Tags: monterey

I'm trying to install Zathura on macOS Monterey by following the instructions on https://github.com/zegervdv/homebrew-zathura, but I'm getting this error whenever I'm trying to open any pdfs.

For those who have installed Zathura on Apple Silicon, can you share how you guys managed to get it working?

Thanks

[image: zathura display error]

Comment: Do you have an X11 Server running?

Comment: I don't know what an X11 Server is, but after googling it, I'm positive I don't have one running.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have installed the X11 version of Zathura. For the version with native macOS integration, follow the instructions beneath **OSX_native_integration**:

```
# unlink installed zathura and girara
brew unlink girara
brew unlink zathura

# install HEAD
brew install girara --HEAD
brew install zathura --HEAD
mkdir -p $(brew --prefix zathura)/lib/zathura
ln -s $(brew --prefix zathura-pdf-poppler)/libpdf-poppler.dylib $(brew --prefix zathura)/lib/zathura/libpdf-poppler.dylib
```

Or, if you haven't installed Zathura yet

```
brew tap zegervdv/zathura
brew install girara --HEAD
brew install zathura --HEAD
brew install zathura-pdf-poppler
mkdir -p $(brew --prefix zathura)/lib/zathura
ln -s $(brew --prefix zathura-pdf-poppler)/libpdf-poppler.dylib $(brew --prefix zathura)/lib/zathura/libpdf-poppler.dylib
```

Comment: I re-installed Zathura and tried the macOS integration, but I'm still getting the same display error.

Comment: girara and zathura are supposed to remain unlinked, correct?

Comment: @jsnchwn Maybe run `brew uninstall zathura girara` first and then use the second set of instructions.

Comment: should I also include zathura-pdf-poppler?

Comment: @jsnchwn It won't hurt, as long as you reinstall it again

Comment: Same display error; I followed your second set of instructions. I'll move on to the first set?

Comment: Same thing even after doing the macOS integration.

Comment: @janchwn Can you open a new tab and start the application again?

Comment: @jsnchwn If the problem still occurs, run the uninstall command again from the comments and then run zathura (without installing it)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking with the new tab and starting the application.

Comment: @janchwn Open a new terminal tab, run the application from there.

Comment: It's the same GTK warning with both of your suggestions.

Comment: @jsnchwn If you are getting the GTK warning even after *uninstalling* Zathura you have another version installed somewhere (use `which zathura` to find out where). Get rid of it first.

Comment: It works now; thank you so much for your patience. One final question: how did you know that I installed the X11 version of zathura?

Comment: @jsnchwn The error message is typical for X11 applications running without an X11 server.